# C# Pass Values from Modeless Form

Tags: c#, forms, modal-dialog, modeless

I am currently in the process of changing my modal form to modeless. The modal form was at the beginning of a method and I utilized the values within the form in this method. Now that I'm changing it to modeless, I have it set to open the form, then in the closed event I call that method. But my problem is, how do I retrieve the values from the form? Since it's closed, I can't use the simple form.Value like I was when the dialog was modal.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the ['FormClosing' event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) and save the data from the form.
I'm fairly certain the 'FormClosing' is the event you need because
The form is not yet disposed when you reach this event.

Comment: Do you think you could show me a quick example? Even if the form isn't disposed at this event, how would I get back to my original method then exit out of the form?